# Can't write to Samba Share from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I have a Windows share mounted on Ubuntu 10.

I've tried mounting it as smbfs & cifs. I can connect & see data on that share when I use either one.

The mount point for Samba is /backup.

If I create a file, say using vi, directly in /backup, it saves just fine.

However, if I try to create a file in /backup using mysqldump or copy a folder using cp, it fails, saying "cannot create regular file...(name of file it is trying to create)...no such file or directory."

What am I doing wrong? How come I can create files on the share with vi, but not anything else? Thank you!

P.S. I am using a user that is "root" at the time of my attempt.

Comment: You do both tasks with root? Could you tell us your permissions on /backup ?

Comment: Yes, as root for both commands. The permission for /backup is 777, owned by root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just guessing, but I would say that if you examine your fstab file, you are mounting the file system without the UTF-8 option (which is required for a ntfs-3g filesystem.  If you remount with that option, then you'll probably find that writing to that share will then work.  Just a guess though.  It's easy to check your mount options.